# How to render "markdowns with html" in a template of vue using 'vue3-markdown-it' or other dependency?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, r-markdown, markdown

I'm using `"vue3-markdown-it": "^1.0.10"` as dependency to be able to render markdown content in my components of vue.

I added the following in `vue.config.json` to enable the dependency on the project

```json
configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.md$/i,
          loader: "raw-loader",
        },
      ],
    },
}
```

And I have the following content in `Home.vue`

```
<template>
...
<Markdown :source="indice" class="indice"/>
<Markdown :source="home"/>
...
</template>

<script>
...
import home_md from '@/markdown/home.md';
import indice_md from '@/markdown/indice.md';
...
data: function() {
    return {
      home: home_md,
      indice: indice_md
    }
  },
...
</script>
```

And in the markdown file `home.md` I have

```
...
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

<img src="https://wpdirecto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/alt-de-una-imagen.png"></img>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
...
```

But it only renders all the markdown syntax, but the html doesn't render for me like it does on github, for example (which is what I'm looking to do)

[output preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4JeU.png)

Is there a way to render as html all that string that it ignores, in addition to rendering the entire markdown part?

I understand that instead of using `<img src="..."></img>` I can use `![](...)` but this is just an example of a need I will need later when using `<div>`